# Extract a word between a word and a character in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use Regex Extract in Google Sheets to extract a word after 'Narrative'.  Please refer to examples below:

*Example 1*:
Asset - Photo,**Narrative - Bubbles**,Campaign - Traffic,Category - Blog

The result should be: Bubbles

*Example 2*:
Campaign - Traffic,Asset - Photo,Category - Blog,**Narrative - Diet**

The result should be: Diet

Since the word Narrative might show up at the end on the line, it can be without a comma.
Ideally, I am wondering if there's a solution to capture both situations, with comma and without. If that is not possible, it would be great to at least have a solution for a case with comma. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "Narrative - (\w+)")))
```

[image: 0]